# Why are the column names of a dataframe getting changed automatically?

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to estimate the parameters for a linear regression model in `R`. The model is of the type: `y=(alpha)+(beta*x)+epsilon`. The task required me to place the values of the parameters systematically in a data frame. I thus created a blank data frame, and then went on appending rows into it for the values of the parameters.

```
df<-data.frame(alpha=double(),beta=double()) #blank dataframe
for(i in 1:1000)
{
    sample_dat<-sampling_model(100,2,5,16,-2,2) #generating 100 samples
    sample_model<-lm(y~x,data=sample_dat) #estimating the linear model
    df<-rbind(df,sample_model$coefficients) #appending the values of the parameters
}
```

Basically, I have a function `sampling_model` which is designed such that it generates random values for `x_i`'s and `epsilon_i`'s (both of which follow some distribution) and gives the values of `y_i`'s adding those two with some fixed value of alpha and beta.

In each iteration of the above loop, we get a pair of values of the estimates of the parameters(alpha and beta) upon fitting a linear model to them. I want to store them in a data frame, which I've named `df`.

Initially (before starting the loop), `names(df)` returned:

```
#[1] "alpha" "beta"
```

However, after appending all those estimates of alpha and beta to `df` (i.e. after the loop), `names(df)` returned:

```
#[1] "X2.4932268478702"  "X5.53432974825338"
```

I am stuck here, asking myself why is this happening. Better to note that these names are also not constant. Like, if I run the above loop one more time and then check the name of the columns, the numbers are all different. Is something overflowing or have I made some mistake in appending the values to the data frame?

Also, I can (and did) get around this problem of 'ambiguous' names simply by:

```
names(df)<-c('alpha','beta')
```

But this does not hide the fact that I made something wrong while appending the estimated parameters in the `df` and I cannot figure that out. Can anyone help me out on how can this be avoided?

---

I am also attaching my `sampling_model` function for convenience:

```
sampling_model<-function(n,alpha,beta,variance,min_range,max_range)
{
    x<-runif(n,min=min_range,max=max_range) #n uniform variates as x_i
    epsilon<-rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=sqrt(variance)) #n normal variates as epsilon_i
    y<-alpha+beta*x+epsilon #the dependant variable y
    return(data.frame(x=x,y=y)) #returns dataframe of x and y
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* this happens, its strange behavior and seems to only happen when the first `rbind` argument has no rows. But `rbind`ing data frame together in a loop is a very inefficient  bad practice and should be avoided. It is famously the 2nd Circle of R Hell in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

The simplest alternative is to initialize your data to the full size, and then fill in each row:

```
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(alpha=double(n),beta=double(n)) #blank dataframe
for(i in 1:n)
{
    sample_dat <- sampling_model(100,2,5,16,-2,2) #generating 100 samples
    sample_model <- lm(y~x,data=sample_dat) #estimating the linear model
    df[i, ] <- sample_model$coefficients #filling in the values of the parameters
}
```

Comment: Well, now I get it. Thanks!